# Use wget to return Web API service call

Tags: wget

We created a Web API service layer that will kick off a job by posting a URL. This service will return the ID of that job when the URL is posted in a browser like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqNhU.jpg

I would like to automate this process, so I am using wget on the command line to call the URL. However, I am not getting the return code that I get in the browser in the wget response. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you getting anything back from the wget command?

Comment: Yes, if I run it with no other options, I get the standard response like this:
Resolving internalqaapp... 172.16.40.167
Connecting to internalqaapp|172.16.40.167|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3 [application/json]

100%[============================================================================>] 3             --.--K/s

15:39:50 (131.54 KB/s) - `2.2' saved [3/3]

I have run with other options I have found with examples, I can get all kinds of data back (links, images, etc.), but not the text.